# How can I fix this damaged Camtasia recorded video file?

Tags: video, encoding, mp4, video-encoding, video-recording

Been recording using `Camtasia Recorder` and then suddenly mac crashed and restarted. I really hope someone here had encountered with a similar case in the past!

I really need to fix that video cause there's no any way to access to that content again..

***MediaInfo***

- MediaInfo of THE DAMAGED FILE

[image: MediaInfo of DAMAGED FILE]

- MediaInfo of A HEALTHY FILE

[image: MediaInfo of HEALTHY FILE]

***Hex view of files***

- Starting of the DAMAGED FILE

[image]

- Starting of a HEALTHY FILE

[image]

- Ending of the DAMAGED FILE

[image]

- Ending of a HEALTHY FILE

[image]

I think it's just about the **incomplete ENDING** of the file as you can see in shots. Is there any way to fix the file?

---

**UPDATE1:**

In case you necessarily need the damaged file to analyze, I was able to reproduce exactly same crash and then made another damaged file.

**A** Damaged file on dropbox :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ubxg95mb8xarbr/DAMAGED.zip?dl=0

A Healthy file with almost same time length on dropbox :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pwtrvbo5qtdua8v/Healthy.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recordings look like MP4 files.

Your good file looks like:

|size| 'mdat' |video|audio|video|...| |size| 'moov' |codec info| |offset to video|offset to audio|offset to video|...|

Your bad file:

|wrong size| 'mdat' |video|audio|video|...|

So your are missing the codec info - which can be taken from your good file. Now I would separate the video from the audio in your bad file assuming that the video chunks are stored |4 byte size||video|. Then I would transform the video from |4 byte size||video| format into Annex B |start code||video| and inject the codec info as SPS and PPS NALs.
I would wrap the AAC audio into ADTS and mux the resulting two files with FFmpeg.

If I couldn't find a tool - I'd create one or contact Camtasia.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I was in a big trouble for last 3 weeks due to a corruption of APFS container of my Mac drive.(https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336223/how-to-fix-my-corrupted-apfs-container). I had lost access to all my accounts including this one. Fortunately I was able to fix it somehow and access my account again. Sorry for this long long delay. Please see the UPDATE1 and let me know if it's possible for you to analyze the DAMAGED file. I hope you manage to rescue the file using the procedure you mentioned above. Dear Markus, I've never needed your help more than now.

Comment: ُI've already tried Camtasia support ticket but no success. They just told me the file is unrecoverable whereas a guy in VideoHelp proved that it's completely recoverable and even took a screenshot of the repaired video file. I'm a illiterate in video encoding field & 2nd half of your answer sounds really advanced and too complicated to be followed by me! I wish you could try to apply it on the fake damaged file above to see what would be the result. I'd really appreciate every click you may do.

Comment: I really need your help, Markus.